# scrapy python find href references recursively

Tags: python, scrapy, href

I'm trying to do an scrapy that find and print all href  from  a  start page:

```
class Ejercicio2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Ejercicio2"
    Ejercicio2 = {}
    category = None
    lista_urls =[] #defino una lista para meter las urls

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Ejercicio2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls = ['http://www.masterdatascience.es/']
    self.allowed_domains = ['www.masterdatascience.es/']
    url = ['http://www.masterdatascience.es/']


def parse(self, response):
    print(response)
    # hay_enlace=response.css('a::attr(href)')
    # if hay_enlace:
    links = response.xpath("a/@href")
    for el in links:
        url = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        print(url)
        next_url = response.urljoin(el.xpath("a/@href").extract_first())
        print(next_url)
        print('pasa por aqui')
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse())
        # yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
        print(next_url)
```

But is not working as expected, not following the "href" references encountered,only the first one.

Comment: Can you try removing the trailing `/` in `allowed_domains`? (`self.allowed_domains = ['www.masterdatascience.es']`)

Answer (score 0):

the code below will print out all the href on the page:

```
import scrapy

class stackoverflow20170129Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stackoverflow20170129"
    allowed_domains = ["masterdatascience.es"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.masterdatascience.es/",]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a/@href'):
           url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
           print url
#           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```

one thing also: worth dropping the www. from the "allowed_domains" - if you go deeper into the website and start getting to pages such as anewpage.masterdatascience.es then including the www. will block that page

Answer (score -2):

You could try modify your xpath to //a/@href